# paypal-django WPP authorization - capture

Tags: django, paypal

I'm trying to integrate payment through PSP `paypal` on a website using the [django-paypal app](https://github.com/johnboxall/django-paypal).

It works fine for standard and it appears to work fine for most of payments pro as well. I'm using the sandbox site and want to test using the `WPP framework` for authorize - capture workflows.

That is, taking a customer's payment information using Paypal's WPP and then authorizing their card for a transaction, but not yet charging it.

Then, after some time has passed, capturing the payment. The [WPP documentation](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_wpp_integrationguide.pdf) shows examples on page 38 for direct pay and page 54 for express checkout.

It uses the `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION` keyword(s), neither of which really show up in the `django-paypal` app as far as I can tell.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to use Django-Paypal to do this sort of transaction? Or am I better off writing my own class for this?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states, you can simply send Authorization for the payment action and then capture it later DoCapture.

If you don't see the option to adjust that in the Django library you'll probably need to extend it or just build your own.